# Odd $\sin/\cos$ integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate
$$\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^5x}dx\ ?$$

I've tried various substitutions with $\sin x = u$ or $\cos x = u$, I've tried using Euler's formula which result in too heavy calculations and I've tried using $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ in various forms without success.

Comment: You tried $u=\cos x$? What was the output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int \frac{\sin^{3}x}{\cos^{5}x}dx=\int \frac{(1-\cos^{2}x)\sin x}{\cos^{5}x}dx$$ and try substitution $$t=\cos x.$$

Answer (score 28):

Another approach:
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^5x}dx&=\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^3x\cos^2x}dx\\
&=\int\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^3\frac{dx}{\cos^2x}\\
&=\int\tan^3x\ d(\tan x)\\
&=\frac14\tan^4x+C.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 9):

Let $u=\cos x$ then $du=-\sin xdx$ so
$$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^5x}dx=-\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^5}du=\frac{u^{-4}}{4}-\frac{u^{-2}}{2}+C=\frac{\cos^{-4}x}{4}-\frac{\cos^{-2}x}{2}+C$$